# How to bring the same activity but different task to the top of the stack?

Tags: android, android-activity

I start activity A(1) and click button in Activity A then it start activity A(2) again but content in activity A(2) change. And I want to bring A(1) to top (swap with A(2) ) How do I do?

Example Flow

1) A(1)------>A(2)
when I click button in A(2), A(1) bring to top of stack.

2) When I backpress from A(1) that bring to top aleardy, it will show A(2).

Thank you and Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Add some code to your question.

Comment: You can always override onBackPressed() in your activity and start any activity from there via intent. Is it that what you want?

Comment: Don't worry, your English is quite good. A little remark: before "." and ",", you don't need a space, only after them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. There is no way to rearrange the activity stack reliably if you have multiple instances of the same `Activity` in the stack. Android wasn't designed for this kind of navigation.

If you really need this type of navigation in your app, you have 2 choices:

1) Don't use the same `Activity` twice. Even if the code and layout is identical you can create another `Activity` that has a different name. In this case, you will have `A` and `B` instead of `A(1)` and `A(2)`. Now you can use `Intent` flags like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to rearrange the stack of activities in your task.

2) Don't start a new instance of `A` if you just want to change the content. Just change the content when the user presses the button. Override `onBackPressed()` and change the content again when the user presses the BACK button. This will give the illusion of 2 activities using only one.